# What is the equivalent function or type in flutter instead of Buffer in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, dart

```
// url is a string, data is a buffer
const signature = (url, data) => {
    const urlBuffer = Buffer.from(url);
    const dataToBeSigned = Buffer.concat([urlBuffer, data]);   
}
```

I am following a documentation of some service, the example given there is of node.js but I want to write the same code in dart. I couldn't find type Buffer in flutter.

Comment: I don't know anything about node.js, but does [`StringBuffer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html) do what you want?

Comment: Actually even I don't know about node.js so am clueless about what is happening in those lines.

Comment: Do you have found an equivalent of Buffer class for Dart?